# how to upload multiple files from angular to web api

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, rest

try to write as video i follow it but the code not work well
always the formdata be null
not transfer any data
the same code work for the upload one file but without looping by  for

```js
export class AddfilesComponent implements OnInit {
  files:any;
  //for show image throw url
  res:any;
  constructor(public httpclient:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  selectfile(a:any){
   this.files=a.target.files;
  }
upload(){
 // console.log(this.files);
let formdata=new  FormData();
for(let file in this.files){
  formdata.append('files',file);
}
 this.httpclient.post("https://localhost:7282/api/home/uploads",formdata).subscribe(a=>{this.res=a,console.log(a)});
 
  }
}
```

```html
<p>addfiles works!</p>
<p>addfile works!</p>
file<input type="file" multiple (change)="selectfile($event)">
<br>
<input type="button" value="upload Files" (click)="upload()"> 
<br>
```

Comment: you can use https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/ uploader with multiple options

Comment: ok, thank you I discover the problem in the code in  the loop should be for(let file of item) instead of for(let file in item) to loop the values of files